# Finding roots of a non linear function - Working precision and accuracy goal error

Tags: equation-solving

Consider the following function

```
F[v_,a_]:=-((v (16 - 176 a + 144 E^(v/2) + 176 a E^(v/2) - 160 E^v - 16 a v - 
    16 E^(v/2) v + 16 a E^(v/2) v + 16 E^v v + 
    16 a E^(v/2) v^2))/((-4 + 4 E^(v/2) + 4 a v) (-4 + 4 E^(v/2) + 
    4 E^(v/2) v)));
```

here `v` is the state variable and `a` is a parameter.

when  I change `a` the function changes the number of solutions (roots, i.e `F[v,a]==0`)

I'm attempting to construct a code in which I'll obtain all roots as a function of `a`. To achieve this what I attempt to do is make a table where I scan all possible initial conditions using `FindRoot` and then delete the duplicates.

I have a problem however using `FindRoot` as it gives me false roots and the following error

```
FindRoot::lstol: The line search decreased the step size to within tolerance specified by AccuracyGoal and PrecisionGoal but was unable to find a sufficient decrease in the merit function. You may need more than MachinePrecision digits of working precision to meet these tolerances.
```

here are two examples where `FindRoot`:

1.finds a false root (where `FindRoot` finds a false root there is only a single one)

```
Plot[F[v, 0.4], {v, -15, 15}]
FindRoot[F[v, 0.4] == 0, {v, 10}]
FindRoot[F[v, 0.4] == 0, {v, -0.1}]
```

[image]

2. finds the correct root where `a` is varied and a new root appears

> ```
> Plot[F1[v, 0.6], {v, -15, 15}]
> FindRoot[F1[v, 0.6] == 0, {v, 10}]
> FindRoot[F1[v, 0.6] == 0, {v, -0.1}]
> ```

[image]

What I'm asking here is how to work out the error produced by `FindRoot` or alternetively, a better way to make a table of all the roots of the function `F[v,a]` in the form of `{{a1,{roots1}},{a2,{roots2}}....}`

Answer (score 1):

Try `NSolve` together with a predefined solution range for v:

```
sol[a_?NumericQ] := NSolve[{F[v, a] == 0, -15 < v < 15}, v]

p1 = Map[{v /. #, 4} &, sol[4]] (* single solution *)
p2 = Map[{v /. #, .75} &, sol[.75]] (* multible solution*)
Show[ContourPlot[F[v, a] == 0, {v, -15, 15}, {a, -5, 5},GridLines ->Automatic], Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Blue, Point[p1], Red, Point[p2]}]]
```

[image]